# How to pass the value of an expression back to data target in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am trying to pass back the id of an element back to my target. I have multiple ace-editor instances on my page. I would like to know which one is sending me a "textchanged" event, so that I can sync the content of the correct tuple in my array.

```
<md-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of function_cards">
    <md-card>
        Some content here.
    <pre>{{card.code}}</pre>
    <pre>{{card.id}}</pre>

    <div ace-editor 
       [text]="code"
       [mode]="'python'"
       [theme]="'eclipse'"
       [options]="options"
       [readOnly]="false"
       [autoUpdateContent]="true"
       (textChanged)="onChange($event)"
       style="min-height: 200px; 
       width:100%; 
       overflow: auto;" 
       (click) = "setId({{card.id}})"></div>
    </md-card>
</md-grid-tile>
```

My typescript code is as follows:

```
private function_cards: CodeEditor[] = [{
    id: 1, 
    code: "something"
},
{
    id: 2,
    code: "something else"
}];

setId(id: number){
    this.text_editor_id = id;
    console.log("CLICKED ON: " + id)
}

onChange(code) {
    console.log("new code", this.text_editor_id);
    this.function_cards[this.text_editor_id].code = code;
}
```

This implementation does not work. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. Also, is this the best way to do this? I need to keep track of changes made in different ng2-ace-editor instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the card id in the onChange event:

```
 (textChanged)="onChange($event, card.id)"
```

The problem you are probably having is that you have these {{ brackets in your click handler and these are not necessary here. This will work:

```
 (click)="setId(card.id)"
```

However I don't believe you need this function. Hope this helps!

Comment: that worked. The {{ brackets caused the issue. I resorted to using your first suggestion. Thank you.